# Show the nearest neighbour to each location in an array of locations

Tags: php

G'day,

Coding in PHP and I have an array with the latitude and longitude decimal coordinates and name of some 5000 locations.

I have a function to calculate the great circle distance in metres between two locations.
function vincentyGreatCircleDistance(
  $latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371008.8)

How can I effieciently find the nearest neighbour for each location in the array?

That is for every location output it's name, the name of the nearest neighbour, plus the distance between them in metres.

Best regards, Lloyd Borrett.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've managed to cobble together a brute force solution that works for the size of the data set. It also gives me the bearing in degrees and a 16 point compass rose value. It's helped me to find a few issues with the data set, which was what I was hoping for.